# Javascript general string type parser

Tags: javascript, jquery, string-parsing

In an HTML form I have a field that can have text entered into it. The text can be a number, boolean or just an string. I want a function that will read the string and return the value parsed to most applicable type. Using jQuery.
This is the code I have written for this. Any comments?

```
var isIntegerRegex = /^\s*(\+|-)?\d+\s*$/,
    isDecimalRegex = /^\s*(\+|-)?((\d+(\.\d+)?)|(\.\d+))\s*$/;

function parseVal(value) {
    if ($.type(value) !== "string") {
        return value;
    } else if (value.search(isIntegerRegex) != -1) {
        return parseInt(value,10);
    } else if (value.search(isDecimalRegex) != -1) {
        return parseFloat(value);
    } else if (value.toLowerCase()==="true") {
        return true;
    } else if (value.toLowerCase()==="false") {
        return false;
    } else {
        return value;
    }
}
```

The Regex's were taken from: http://ntt.cc/2008/05/10/over-10-useful-javascript-regular-expression-functions-to-improve-your-web-applications-efficiency.html

Comment: This'd probably be better on Codereview

Answer (score 2):

What about this:

```
​function parse(string) {
    var number = parseFloat(string);

    if (!isNaN(number)) return number;
    if (string.toLowerCase() === "true") return true;
    if (string.toLowerCase() === "false") return false;
    return string;
};
```